# Postgres 9.3 JSON Output multi-dimensional object

Tags: json, postgresql

Given this query:-

```
SELECT id as id,
       attributes->>'name' as file_name, 
       status 
from workflow.events 
where schema='customer' 
  and type='FILE_UPLOAD'

id,file_name, status
1,name,status
2,name2,status2
```

I want to output this structure:-

```
{
 "1" :{"id" :"1", "file_name" : "name", "status" : "status1"},
 "2" :{"id" :"2", "file_name" : "name2","status" : "status2"}
}
```

I can do it at the moment using string functions but this seems messy and inefficient. CAn it be done using the native postgresql json functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON output in Postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198625/json-output-in-postgresql)

Comment: There are a couple of useful json functions, namely row_to_json(), which should come in handy: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get two records with json, use [row_to_json()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html) function:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        id as id,
        attributes->>'name' as file_name, 
        status 
     from workflow.events 
     where schema='customer' and type='FILE_UPLOAD'
)
select row_to_json(c) from cte as c
```

output:

```
{"id":1,"file_name":"name","status":"status"}
{"id":2,"file_name":"name2","status":"status2"}
```

If you want to get json array:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        id as id,
        attributes->>'name' as file_name, 
        status 
     from workflow.events 
     where schema='customer' and type='FILE_UPLOAD'
)
select json_agg(c) from cte as c
```

output:

```
[{"id":1,"file_name":"name","status":"status"}, 
 {"id":2,"file_name":"name2","status":"status2"}]
```

But for you desired output, I can only suggest string transformation:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        id::text as id,
        file_name, 
        status 
    from workflow.events 
    where schema='customer' and type='FILE_UPLOAD'
)
select ('{' || string_agg('"' || id || '":' || row_to_json(c), ',') || '}')::json from cte as c
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a22b1/7)</kbd>**

Comment: The final step with concatenation, that should be good enough after  `row_to_json()` did most of the work. I'll delete my answer since you undeleted yours, and your answer is is good.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter, I see that PostgreSQL have json_each to fetch data from json structured like this output, but seems it don't have function to do it other way around as OP wants :(

Comment: There is very little of examples about those functionalities with JSON in postgres 9.3, this answer is enlightening! Thanks Roman