# generate json with column value as json dict key

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm using postgres 9.2, and I'm trying to construct a query that generates json in a particular format. I've gotten pretty close with a simple `json_agg` expression, but now I'm stuck moving forwards.

I have a simple three-table schema, the definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE project (
    id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name    varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (name)    
);

CREATE TABLE test (
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name        varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    project_id  integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES project(id),
);

CREATE TABLE data (
    id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    date_entered    timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    data            json NOT NULL,
    test_id         integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (test_id) REFERENCES test(id)
);
```

After inserting some data like so:

```
INSERT INTO project (id, name) VALUES (0, 'my_project');
INSERT INTO test (id, name, project_id) VALUES (0, 'test0', 0);
INSERT INTO data (date_entered, data, test_id) VALUES (TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2014-04-15T09:34:41.454999 z', '["some", "data"]', 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, name, project_id) VALUES (1, 'test1', 0);
INSERT INTO data (date_entered, data, test_id) VALUES (TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2014-04-15T09:34:41.454999 z', '["some", "data"]', 1);
```

I'd like to construct a query that returns:

```
{
  "test0": {
    "first_data": "2014-04-15 09:35:10.394+00",
    "data_points": 1
  },
  "test1": {
    "first_data": "2014-04-15 09:35:10.394+00",
    "data_points": 1
  }
}
```

The closest I've gotten to this solution is with this query:

```
SELECT
    json_agg(data) as data
FROM (
    SELECT
        test.name as test_name,
        min(data.date_entered) as first_data,
        count(data.id) as data_points
    FROM test
    INNER JOIN data on data.test_id = test.id
    INNER JOIN project on test.project_id = project.id
    WHERE project.name = 'my_project'
    GROUP BY test.name
) as data;
```

which returns this:

```
[
  {
    "test_name":"test0",
    "first_data":"2014-04-15 09:34:41.454999+00",
    "data_points":1
  },
  {
    "test_name":"test1",
    "first_data":"2014-04-15 09:34:41.454999+00",
    "data_points":1
  }
]
```

I've tried various odd uses of row_to_json and array_to_json, but I can't seem to shift the test_name value to be the key in the outer dictionary.

Is this even possible? Am I abusing postgres' json generation functions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378523/postgres-9-3-json-output-multi-dimensional-object

Comment: @Fabricator - that answer uses ugly string concatenation. Is there no other way? If that's the best postgres can do I'll do it in my application instead...

Answer (score 0):

You indeed do better by *jsonifying* with an application language. With that said here is an *ugly string concatenation* solution

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/38473/1)

```
select
    (format(
        '{"%s": {"first_data": "%s", "data_points": %s}}', 
        test.name,
        min(data.date_entered),
        count(data.id)
    ))::json as data
from test
inner join data on data.test_id = test.id
inner join project on test.project_id = project.id
where project.name = 'my_project'
group by test.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
    SELECT jsonb_object_agg(test.name, jsonb_build_object('first_data', min(data.date_entered), 'data_points', count(data.id)))
    FROM test
    INNER JOIN data on data.test_id = test.id
    INNER JOIN project on test.project_id = project.id
    WHERE project.name = 'my_project'
    GROUP BY test.name
```