# Azure SQL: generate JSON with column as key

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have the below data in my sql server table

| Name | Value | ValueHash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| country | aaa | zzz |
| lastname | ccc | yyy |
| email | a@a.com | xxx |
| firstName | bbb | www |

And I want the below Json using sql query

```
{
    "lastname": {
      "value": "ccc",
      "valueHash": "yyy"
    },
    "email": {
      "value": "a@a.com",
      "valueHash": "xxx"
    },
    "firstName": {
      "value": "bbb",
      "valueHash": "www"
    },
    "country": {
      "value": "aaa",
      "valueHash": "zzz"
    }
}
```

I could come up with the below query

```
select Value as 'value', ValueHash as 'valueHash'  from user
where id=752594
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Which returns

```
    {
      "value": "ccc",
      "valueHash": "yyy"
    },
    {
      "value": "a@a.com",
      "valueHash": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "value": "bbb/T1B+4nzpVhb0M",
      "valueHash": "www"
    },
    {
      "value": "aaa",
      "valueHash": "zzz"
    }
```

Tried the solution from [generate json with column value as json dict key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400997/generate-json-with-column-value-as-json-dict-key) but am getting compiler error.

Can someone please help me with this? TIA

Comment: You have more in your table than just those columns if you have `WHERE id=752594` in your query.  I'm assuming `id` is the identifier that relates the rows to form the JSON you're interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have `JSON_AGG` or `JSON_OBJECT_AGG`. So you need to hack it with `STRING_AGG` and `STRING_ESCAPE`

```sql
SELECT
  '{' +
  STRING_AGG(
  CONCAT(
    '"',
    STRING_ESCAPE(u.Name, 'json'),
    '":',
    v.json
  ), ','
 ) + '}'
FROM [user] u
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      u.Value AS value,
      u.ValueHash AS valueHash
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) v(json)
WHERE u.id = 752594;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9e8d7020e6e4e0c0b2ee206292c2bafb)

Comment: Thanks your solution works, one thing I noticed is, some of my hash values in the DB are like `R5/T1B` but in the json am getting it as `R5\/T1B`, is there a way to get the original hash value without additional escape characters in the json result

Comment: That's the way SQL Server escapes it, it is a bit over-cautious in escaping. It makes no difference because when you deserialize it with any decent deserializer then it will be unescaped.

Answer (score 1):

This produces a similar results. Telling SQL Server to not use an array wrapper on the inner values results in it escaping the results:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('country','aaa','zzz'),
                ('lastname','ccc','yyy'),
                ('email','a@a.com','xxx'),
                ('firstName','bbb','www'))V(Name,Value,ValueHash))
SELECT (SELECT value,
               ValueHash
        WHERE YT.Name = 'lastname'
        FOR JSON PATH) AS lastname,
       (SELECT value,
               ValueHash
        WHERE YT.Name = 'email'
        FOR JSON PATH) AS email,
       (SELECT value,
               ValueHash
        WHERE YT.Name = 'firstName'
        FOR JSON PATH) AS firstName,
       (SELECT value,
               ValueHash
        WHERE YT.Name = 'country'
        FOR JSON PATH) AS country
FROM YourTable YT
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Comment: I can not hardcode the result query values like `'email' lastname firstName country` in the query it self I need generic one like in the other answer since I need to generate the json for various users and each user has different `Name` values

Comment: That was a note you should have included in your question, @OTUser .

Answer (score 0):

If you ever wanted to return more than a single object, assuming you have a column `id` in the table as you seem to imply with your `WHERE` clause, you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT,
                  Name VARCHAR(100),
                  Value VARCHAR(100),
                  ValueHash VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @t (id, Name, Value, ValueHash)
VALUES (1, 'country', 'aaa', 'zzz'),
       (1, 'lastname', 'ccc', 'yyy'),
       (1, 'email', 'a@a.com', 'xxx'),
       (1, 'firstName', 'bbb', 'www'),
       (2, 'country', 'aaa2', 'zzz2'),
       (2, 'lastname', 'ccc2', 'yyy2'),
       (2, 'email', 'a2@a2.com', 'xxx2'),
       (2, 'firstName', 'bbb2', 'www2');


SELECT (SELECT Value, ValueHash
        FROM @t
        WHERE id = t1.id AND Name = 'lastname'
       FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) lastname,
       (SELECT Value, ValueHash
        FROM @t
        WHERE id = t1.id AND Name = 'email'
       FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) email,
       (SELECT Value, ValueHash
        FROM @t
        WHERE id = t1.id AND Name = 'firstName'
       FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) firstName,
       (SELECT Value, ValueHash
        FROM @t
        WHERE id = t1.id AND Name = 'country'
       FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) country
FROM @t t1
WHERE t1.Name = 'lastname'
FOR JSON PATH;
```

Note, as with Larnu's solution it will also escape the values for `Value` and `ValueHash`.

Comment: I can not hardcode the result query values like `'email' lastname firstName country` in the query it self I need generic one like in the other answer since I need to generate the json for various users and each user has different `Name` values

Comment: Yeah, saw that comment on Larnu's answer right as I was posting mine...  Would have been nice to know up front.